# How to load and display tiff images in TImage control?

Tags: delphi, tiff, delphi-xe2

I am currently working on Delphi XE2 trial version. I want to load and display TIFF images in TImage control without using any third party component/library.

I tried below code but it is not woking for me.

```
Procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject); 
Var 
     OleGraphic               : TOleGraphic; 
     fs                       : TFileStream; 
     Source                   : TImage; 
     BMP                      : TBitmap; 
Begin 
     Try 
          OleGraphic := TOleGraphic.Create; 

          fs := TFileStream.Create('c:\testtiff.dat', fmOpenRead Or fmSharedenyNone); 
          OleGraphic.LoadFromStream(fs); 

          Source := Timage.Create(Nil); 
          Source.Picture.Assign(OleGraphic); 

          BMP := TBitmap.Create; 
          bmp.Width := Source.Picture.Width; 
          bmp.Height := source.Picture.Height; 
          bmp.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, source.Picture.Graphic); 

          image1.Picture.Bitmap := bmp;
     Finally 
          fs.Free; 
          OleGraphic.Free; 
          Source.Free; 
          bmp.Free; 
     End; 
End;
```

Please advice.

Comment: If the file extension was a standard tiff extension, this would be a one-liner, image1.Picture.LoadFromFile(MyTiffFile). Otherwise, this SO question may help you [how-to-load-an-arbitrary-image-from-a-blob-stream-into-a-timage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251504/how-to-load-an-arbitrary-image-from-a-blob-stream-into-a-timage)

Comment: I wonder if this code came from the sample in http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/en/showcode.php?id=2012 (dated 2004). I just found effectively the same code in a rarely explored part of the codebase I work on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in my comment, if the file extension is the standard tiff extension the code to open the file is trivial :

```
image1.Picture.LoadFromFile(MyTiffFile);
```

If not, follow the answer from dwrbudr.

Here is an example :

```
procedure LoadBitmapFromFile( aImage : TImage; tiffFilename : String);
var
  tiffIm : TWICImage;
  ext : String;
begin
  ext := SysUtils.ExtractFileExt(tiffFilename);
  if (ext = '.tif') or (ext = '.tiff')
    then aImage.Picture.LoadFromFile(tiffFilename)
    else begin
      tiffIm:= TWICImage.Create;
      try
        tiffIm.LoadFromFile(tiffFilename);
        aImage.Picture.Bitmap.Assign(tiffIm);
      finally
        tiffIm.Free;
      end;
    end;
end;
```

See also [`TWICImage`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Graphics.TWICImage), which works for XP SP3 and up.

Answer (score 6):

```
     tiff := TWICImage.Create;
     tiff.LoadFromFile(Filename);
     ABitmap.Assign(tiff);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `GDI+`:

```
uses ..., ActiveX, GDIPAPI, GDIPOBJ, GDIPUTIL;

function LoadImageFromFile(const FileName: string; Bmp: TBitmap): Boolean;
var
  GPImage: TGPImage;
  encoderClsid: TGUID;
  MemStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  Result := False;
  GPImage := TGPImage.Create(FileName);
  try
    if GPImage.GetLastStatus = Ok then
    begin
      MemStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
      try
        GetEncoderClsid('image/bmp', encoderClsid);
        if GPImage.Save(TStreamAdapter.Create(MemStream), encoderClsid) = Ok then
        begin
          MemStream.Position := 0;
          Bmp.LoadFromStream(MemStream);
          Result := True;
        end;
      finally
        MemStream.Free;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    GPImage.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  LoadImageFromFile('D:\ML_10222.tif', Image1.Picture.Bitmap);
end;
```

---

I also want to mention Synopse `TSynPicture` (GDI+ wrapper):  https://stackoverflow.com/a/6251810/937125

---

**EDIT:** GDI+ `TGPImage` also supports multiple tiff frames/pages:

To get the frames count use:

```
GPImage.GetFrameCount(GDIPAPI.FrameDimensionPage);
```

To set the active frame use:

```
GPImage.SelectActiveFrame(GDIPAPI.FrameDimensionPage, Index);
```

Note that [`TSynPicture`](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2010/03/20/GIF,-TIF,-PNG-and-JPG-pictures-TGraphic-read/write-via-GDI) also supports multiple frames.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if TIF contains multiple images, you can specify the image you want to load using the `FrameIndex` property before loading the image in **TWicImage**

With `FrameCount` you get the number of available images in the TIF file

`FrameIndex` range is 0 to `FrameCount`-1