# How to load Tiff image into Timage in Delphi 2007 without using any third party libraries?

Tags: delphi, tiff, delphi-2007

I am trying to use `image1.Picture.LoadFromFile(MyTiffFile)` to load tiff file into `Timage`, but tiff is not supported.

Is there any way to achieve this without using a any third party libraries?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load and display tiff images in TImage control?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7845359/how-to-load-and-display-tiff-images-in-timage-control)

Comment: is it Delphi 7 or 2007? both does not support tiff out of the box. you could consider using GDI+ for this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33550199/937125

Comment: TIFF support was added to `TBitmap` for .NET in Delphi 2009.  TIFF support was added to VCL via `TWICImage` in Delphi 2010.

Comment: I have rolled back your edit. you specifically asked for a solution without using a any third party. you got an answer and useful leads.

Answer (score 6):

> How to convert tiff image to `TImage` in Delphi 2007 without using any third party libraries?

Delphi 2007 does not ship with support for tiff images. Since you do not wish to use third party libraries, you must write your own tiff decoder.

Start by reading the [tiff format documentation](https://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/tiff/TIFF6.pdf). Once you've done that you'll realise the magnitude of the task and elect to use a third party library.

Comment: Thanks,Now i understand the toughness. But i thought it would be easier. Anyways i have found a useful link which helps,  http://www.asmail.be/msg0055571626.html using library called LibTiffDelphi.